# No get method providing array access - error when assigning new values ​to the matrix

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin

I am working with opencv on android for the development of an image segmentation application, but specifically with the watershed algorithm. I'm opening the image and creating a mask with the same size as the image and passing 0 for all the rows and columns of that mask. However, in the following step, which is to add new values ​​for certain rows and columns of this matrix, I have the error: No get method providing array access
With that, I am not able to pass the new values ​​to the matrix, can someone help me with this?

COde:

```
   // Load the image
   val srcOriginal = Imgcodecs.imread(currentPhotoPath)

    // Create a blank image of zeros (same dimension as img)
    val markers = Mat.zeros(srcOriginal.rows(), srcOriginal.cols(), CvType.CV_32F)

    // Example assigning a new value to a matrix index
    markers.put(0,0,255)
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV library in java doesn't take input Int as a parameter. You can see in the method declaration https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#get(int,int,int%5B%5D).

Pass an IntArray for RGB values along with row and col values:

```kotlin
// Replace row and col with your values
markers.put(row, col, intArrayOf(0,0,255))
```

Comment: Animesh you can helpe me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067408/for-input-string-mat-00cv-32fc1-iscont-true-issubmat-false-nativeobj-0x

Comment: @Carlos Diego looks like there is some problem in the toInt() call, will see your problem later when I'm free, upvoted.

Comment: Thank you so much. see you later

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
markers.put(0,0,X);
```

where x is array containing pixel vales (because it may be RGB,GRAY SCALE,etc)
In Java you can use Mat::get() and Mat::put() methods.

[Read this for more details.](https://answers.opencv.org/question/5/how-to-get-and-modify-the-pixel-of-mat-in-java/)

Comment: Mahmoud, I did as you suggested, but I have a new error that I updated in the question

Comment: Instead of 255 use array with RGB value